# How does ASP.NET WebPages implement extensionless URLs?

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

I'd like to implement the same thing for my own build providers.

---

I'm talking about an ASP.NET Webpages application, in Visual Studio: File > New Website > ASP.NET Website (Razor)

---

Works with Cassini, so it's not an IIS Express thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it, it's an HTTP module, `System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule`
This module checks if the file exists, and if it does it creates a handler from that file and remaps the request to that handler.

Comment: do you have a complete sample anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Razor is a templating engine. It has nothing to do with URLs. They are handled by the ASP.NET routing engine. Extensionless URLs are supported starting from IIS 7.0. In IIS 6.0 you need to associate the aspnet_isapi extension with all incoming requests if you want to support extensionless urls.

Comment: It's routing then ? I'm talking about when you request a razor file without registering any route.

Comment: What kind of application are you talking about? Normally razor files shouldn't be requested directly. Are you talking about WebMatrix? If, yes that it builds on top of the ASP.NET engine and the IIS Express web server which supports extensionless urls.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I've updated the question to answer your question. It works with Cassini as well, the question is, how?

Comment: So you are creating a new ASP.NET website. Also urls are not extensionles. They are of the form: `/sitename/default.cshtml`. The way this works is that the web server (Cassini in your case) receives the request to the razor template and passes it to the ASP.NET engine which will renders the HTML.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: eh, no. URLs are extensionless, this works:  
http://localhost:50209/WebSite2/About , where the razor file is ~/About.cshtml

Comment: @Max, this is a feature that has been introduced in ASP.NET 4.0. It allows to automatically rewrite requests for known extensions such as .cshtml and .vbhtml.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Then, what are the known extensions, and how I can register my own ? I doubt what you are saying though, if it's an ASP.NET feature not limited to WebPages then why doesn't it work with .aspx ?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Yes, that explains the page compilation part, but not the extensionless URL mapping part, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this information in regard to the "Routing" that you might find handy if you are building an ASP.Net WebPages site w/o MVC3 and wanted to mention it.

[Creating More Readable and Searchable URLs - About Routing](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior#Creating_More_Readable_and_Searchable_URLs)

HTH